# Attributes from an hstore-column as separate columns in a view?

Tags: postgresql, view, hstore

Let's assume we have a table where it has two columns, one an ID and one an hstore column, which stores key/value pairs.

You could query that column as such:

```
SELECT name, attributes->'device' as device
FROM products
WHERE attributes->'edition'= 'ebook'
```

Can you create a view for this table where the keys/values appear as columns in the view instead of all in the `hstore` column?

Example: I have an hstore key where it might have the key of amenity.  I want to create a view showing the the ID and the amenity values in a new view.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can.

```
CREATE VIEW v_ebooks AS
SELECT products_id, attributes->'device' AS device
FROM   products
WHERE  attributes->'edition'= 'ebook';
```

[SQL Fiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4c496/2)

But only for a **static** set of columns. Dynamic output of all possible attributes in an [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html) column conflicts with the requirement that the return type has to be declared at creation time.

This later answer provides a completely dynamic solution (in two steps):

- [Dynamically convert hstore keys into columns for an unknown set of keys](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94717/converting-hstore-keys-into-columns-in-postgres/123006#123006)

Comment: Thanks Erwin.  So does that mean if all keys are not present in all hstore columns, then an issue may arise?

Comment: @josh1234: Columns will just be NULL for rows where the key is not found.