# Dynamically convert hstore keys into columns for an unknown set of keys

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, hstore, pivot

I have a database that stores a bunch of custom fields using `hstore`. In order to merge it into another database that doesn't support `hstore`, I'd like to split the keys into extra columns.

Users can add new custom fields and so I can't rely on knowledge of the keys ahead of time. Which makes the answer at ["Attributes from an hstore-column as separate columns in a view?"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58279/attributes-from-an-hstore-column-as-separate-columns-in-a-view) not applicable to my problem.

Where a record doesn't have a key present in other records, it should get the same column with a **null** value.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done, very efficiently, too. Not in a single statement, though, since SQL demands to know the return type at call time. So you need two steps. The solution involves a *number of advanced techniques* ...

Assuming the same table as [@Denver in his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94728/3684):

```
CREATE TABLE hstore_test (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
, hstore_col hstore
);
```

### Solution 1: Simple `SELECT`

After I wrote the crosstab solution below it struck me that a simple "brute force" solution is probably faster. Basically, the query [@Denver already posted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94728/3684), built dynamically:

#### Step 1a: Generate query

```
SELECT format(
     'SELECT id, h->%s
      FROM  (SELECT id, hstore_col AS h FROM hstore_test) t;'
    , string_agg(quote_literal(key) || ' AS ' || quote_ident(key), ', h->')
   ) AS sql 
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT key
   FROM   hstore_test, skeys(hstore_col) key
   ORDER  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

The subquery `(SELECT id, hstore_col AS h FROM hstore_test)` is just to get in the column alias `h` for your `hstore` column.

#### Step 1b: Execute query

This generates a query of the form:

```
SELECT id, h->'key1' AS key1, h->'key2' AS key2, h->'key3' AS key3
FROM  (SELECT id, hstore_col AS h FROM hstore_test) t;
```

Result:

```
 id | key1  | key2  | key3
----+-------+-------+-------
  1 | val11 | val12 | val13
  2 | val21 | val22 |
  3 |       |       |        -- for a row where hstore_col IS NULL
```

### Solution 2: `crosstab()`

For *lots* of keys this *may* perform better. Probably not. You'll have to test. Result is the same as for solution 1.

You need the additional extension `tablefunc` which provides the `crosstab()` function. **Read this first** if you are not familiar:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)

#### Step 2a: Generate query

```
SELECT format(
   $s$SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     $$SELECT h.id, kv.*
       FROM   hstore_test h, each(hstore_col) kv
       ORDER  BY 1, 2$$
   , $$SELECT unnest(%L::text[])$$
   ) AS t(id int, %s text);
   $s$
 , array_agg(key)  -- escapes strings automatically
 , string_agg(quote_ident(key), ' text, ')  -- needs escaping!
   ) AS sql 
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT key
   FROM   hstore_test, skeys(hstore_col) key
   ORDER  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

Note the nested levels of [dollar-quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860).

I use this explicit form in the main query instead of the short `CROSS JOIN` in the auxiliary query to preserve rows with empty or NULL `hstore` values:

```
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL each(hstore_col) kv ON TRUE
```

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Related:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514334/939860)

#### Step 2b: Execute query

This generates a query of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     $$SELECT h.id, kv.*
       FROM   hstore_test h
       LEFT   JOIN LATERAL each(hstore_col) kv ON TRUE
       ORDER  BY 1, 2$$
   , $$SELECT unnest('{key1,key2,key3}'::text[])$$
   ) AS t(id int, key1 text, key2 text, key3 text);
```

You may want to inspect it for plausibility before running the first time. This should deliver optimized performance.

### Notes

- Both solutions work for *any* number of keys up to the [physical limit of ~ 1600 columns in a Postgres table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html).
- Both also work for keys of *any* shape or form up to the [maximum length for identifiers, which is 63 bytes per default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218026/939860).
- Besides the [hstore function `each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) that was [already mentioned by s.m.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122945/3684), I also use the related function [`skeys()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) to identify keys.
- Be sure to quote column names correctly to avoid possible **SQL injection** attacks by way of maliciously formed key names. I take care of that with [`quote_literal()` and `quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).

Comment: Thanks again! If anyone's interested, the cost for my use case for solution 1 was `Planning time: 0.615 ms`, `Execution time: 2474.708 ms` to generate the query. And `Planning time: 0.534 ms`,  `Execution time: 3956.939 ms` to run it. 

And solution 2: `Planning time: 5.079 ms`, `Execution time: 2420.472 ms` to generate the query and `Planning time: 0.034 ms`, `Execution time: 4009.264 ms` to run it.

So not a lot of difference between the two for a table with 1255409 rows and 27 unique keys in the hstore_col.

Answer (score 5):

I realize I'm a bit late—and by now you sure have it figured out—but, seeing the comment you left on Denver Timothy's answer, I thought I would leave an answer for everybody else:

```
select (each(hstore_col)).key from hstore_test;
```

This will create a row for each `key` contained in `hstore_col`, so you won't need to know what the keys are beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the `->` operator on the column (see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/hstore.html)).

Records without the same key in other records will show as NULL.

```
create table hstore_test (id serial, hstore_col hstore);
insert into hstore_test (hstore_col) values ('key1=>val11, key2=>val12, key3=>val13'), ('key1=>val21, key2=>val22');
select hstore_col->'key1' as key1, hstore_col->'key2' as key2, hstore_col->'key3' as key3 from hstore_test;
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ key1  │ key2  │ key3  │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ val11 │ val12 │ val13 │
│ val21 │ val22 │ NULL  │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
(2 rows)
```

[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58279/attributes-from-an-hstore-column-as-separate-columns-in-a-view?rq=1) is a similar answer.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [s.m.'s answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122945/207145) it seems you can combine `EACH()` with both `.key` and `.value` to generate columns automatically.

Setup test table like in [Ian Timothy's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94728/207145):

```
create table hstore_test (id serial, hstore_col hstore);
insert into hstore_test (hstore_col) values ('key1=>val11, key2=>val12, key3=>val13'), ('key1=>val21, key2=>val22');
```

Query

```
SELECT id, (EACH(hstore_col)).key, (EACH(hstore_col)).value FROM hstore_test;
```

which returns

```
 id | key  | value 
----+------+-------
  1 | key1 | val11
  1 | key2 | val12
  1 | key3 | val13
  2 | key1 | val21
  2 | key2 | val22
```

I was a bit unsure whether two `EACH()` inside the same query are guaranteed to produce the same order. I found an [example in the hstore documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/hstore.html#id-1.11.7.26.8) using the same mechanism so I guess it's explicitly supported.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good addition. I can't remember why I selected Erwin's answer over s.m.'s but it might have been because of this? It looks much simpler anyway